# Is Repair needed if all operations are quorum

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Is Repair really needed if all operations execute at quorum.
Repair is generally needed to ensure all nodes are in sync, but quorum already ensures success is only returned when the quorum is in sync.
So if all operations execute at quorum, then do we need repair?

In our use-case, we never update records, we simply add then delete the record.  (If we see the message after a 'delete' failure is ok, it is not disastrous).In fact - a repair could bring the record back to life..that would be undesirable (but not disastrous)

I would think with this situation, unless there was corruption of one of the nodes, we would not need repair.

I would also argue with this setup, even if delete succeeded, and we saw the record again, it would not be a 'big-deal'.  As such I think we could in fact set gc_grace=0, if the quroum operation succeeded, then only 2 would be left..which would never give us quorum against those 'offending nodes, as such we would never see those records anyways (unless..a node dies).

So if a node dies post delete (assume 5 nodes 3 for quorum),
then we have 'stale-mate' 2vs2 and cannot achieve quorum, however hint-repair would kick if one of those records were read again (I'm not clear if this WILL run, or only runs the configured chance amount I.E. 10% is the default if we had quorum failure?). 
Either with if gc_grace=0, it would likely come back to life after the delete, so maybe having gc_grace=24 hours (to allow read-repair to correct) would reduce the chance of seeing the record again.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic thought process is sound - if you write with quorum and read with quorum and never overwrite, then yes, you can likely get by without repair.

You MAY need to run repair if you have to rebuild a failed node, as it's possible that the replacement could miss one of the replicas, and you'd be left with one of three, which may be missed upon read. If that happens, having run incremental repairs previously would make subsequent repairs faster, but it's not strictly necessary.

Your final two paragraphs aren't necessarily accurate - your logic in those is flawed (with 5 nodes and 1 dying, there is no 2v2 stalemate for quorum, that's fundamentally misunderstanding how quorum works). Hints are also best effort and only within a limited window, and read repair isn't guaranteed unless you change read repair to non-default settings.

Comment: Interesting, so in the situation where we have 5 nodes (replicated to all) 1 of nodes dies, (after we have written/delete at quorum), and replication failed (so at the time of death), we have situation where the records exists say on 2 nodes (deleted) and un-deleted in the other 2 what would happen on read at quorum level?  I assume it would fail, but may trigger a read-repair, such that the next read may see the record was deleted.

Comment: When you read at quorum, Cassandra chooses 3 of the remaining 4 nodes and asks for the value of the cell. Of those 3, 1 is guaranteed to be the right data (delete marker) - the mismatch between the three will then force a blocking read repair, and the right data (the delete) will be pushed to all live replicas. It will NOT fail, it will repair and respond.

Comment: To be explicit: in some databases, consensus / resolution is based on which value exists on the most / majority of replicas. In cassandra, the resolution is timestamp first, and a lexical compare second (if timestamps are exact matches). In this scenario, if you had 5 replicas (RF=5), and only one 'right' answer with the highest timestamp, that one right answer still wins as long as it's included in the query (which you can guarantee with active repair or strong enough consistency level on read)